# Need to move file names in a directory with path to a file using unix script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I tried using this code:

```
cd /data/sources/;
ls $PWD/Asset_* >> /data/processing/asset_files.txt;
```

But it works only for small number files not for higher number of files.

How to do it effectively?

Comment: Try to use find(1) for such a task. In your command, the shell  loads ALL the file names to pass them to ls(1). The command line after expansion can get huge.

Comment: What do you mean by **works only for small number files not for higher number of files** ? It takes too long or won't work at all?

Comment: @ImanKianrostami, you code may not work if you have space (or other special characters) in filename

Comment: @RomeoNinov You are right man. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: It doesn't work at all failing with error code  32256

Comment: -bash: /bin/find: Argument list too long...failing with the error

Comment: Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Why don't you use a for loop to write file names one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your script on this way:

```
cd /data/sources/
find $PWD -type f -name "Asset_*">> /data/sources/processing/asset_files.txt
```

Comment: Hi Romeo,Its working for smaller files but not with all the files.

Comment: @Sahilkhan, can you clarify? And give examples for files on which it work on on which it do not work.

Comment: It doesn't work at all failing with error code  32256

Comment: I kept two files and tested , it worked but when I am running on production, which has 1 million files, it is failing with error code 32256.

Comment: @Sahilkhan, I edit my code. Seems like you have a lot of subdirectories on one level

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it doesnt have any subdirectory... I corrected the above code

Comment: I want to copy filenames( with path) starting with Asset_* into a file of other directory

Comment: failing with error:- -bash: /bin/find: Argument list too long

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Ehat should I do if I have to move files also in the new directory

Comment: Hei Romeo, I did that ...please comment on that

Comment: "Need to move file names with path to a file in a directory along with files using unix script" that is the heading

Comment: @Sahilkhan, i see you have already answer and it's more or less what I will propose :)

Comment: Hi Romeo, this tim i have to move files and not just the file names

Comment: Exactly, You have answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54922824/2908599  The idea is to add `-exec mv ......`

Comment: Added my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using a for loop:

```
cd /data/sources/;
for filename in $PWD/Asset_*; do
    echo $filename >> /data/processing/asset_files.txt;
done
```

Comment: It echo just the word `filename`, not the name of the file

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes I forgot to add put $ here. Iedited the answer.