# Move file names with path to a file in a directory along with files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I was moving only the file names in a text file which was working using:

```
cd /data/sources/
find $PWD -type f -name "Asset_*">> /data/processing/asset_files.txt
```

But, I also need to:

1. Move `Asset_*` files also in `/data/processing/`.
2. Move first 1000 files into `/data/processing/`.

How do I add these two things?

Comment: Your specs are not clear. Moving `Asset_*` files is easy with `-exec` option of find. But what are the "first" 1000 files? Alphabetical, creation time, modify time? And what is the difference between 1. and 2. for Asset_* files?

Comment: in 2) I want to move 1000 files for testing purpose.

Comment: in 1) if with 1000 files it works then I will move all the files

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring answer of @Dominique you can use find command and move the files. THis can take a lot of time (depend of number of files)
And the command is like:

```
cd /data/sources/
find $PWD -type f -name "Asset_*" -exec mv {} /target_dir \;
```

If you want to move exactly 1000 files you can do it with something like

```
a=1
cd /data/sources/
for i in $PWD/Asset_*
do
mv "$i" /target_dir
a=$(($a + 1))
if [ "$a" -gt 1000 ]
then break
fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you Romeo and Dominique.
And what if I want to move 1000 file of Asset_* , how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong track, wanting to copy/move 1000 entries. You seem to have a lot of `Asset_*` files (over 1000) and by limiting the number to 1000, you want to check if the behaviour is right and then do it for the whole bunch.
Although this seems correct, the limiting to 1000 is quite a burden and will make your script complicated for no purpose.
I'd propose another approach : imagine you have filenames like this:

```
Asset_00000
Asset_00001
Asset_00002
...
Asset_00010
Asset_00011
...
Asset_99999
```

Then, you might first try to do you thing, using `Asset_0000*`, and then, once you've verified everything is correct, do it for all `Asset_*` files.

As far as the moving is concerned, you can do this as follows:

```
find /directory -name "Asset_0000*" -exec mv {} /target_directory \;
```

Comment: File name is not like Asset_0000, its random. I want o move 1000 files